# How to find all events from city using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get all events from city (for example Warsaw) using Facebook Graph API. I found "search" command to do it:

```
/v2.4/search?q=Warsaw&type=event&want_localized_name=true&limit=5000
```

This is not solution, becouse there is one problem: I get only 200-300 events, but I know I should get minimum 1000, even when I set the limit for 5000.

Documentation on the Facebook page is incomplete: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.4

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not incomplete, what you are trying to achieve is just not possible and you are using the wrong docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search. You can search for an event by name and you can search for a Facebook Place by latitude/longitude, but you can´t search for an event by city.